# convert string value to md5

Tags: c#, sql, cryptography, byte, md5

I'm trying to convert String to md5
that what i did :

```
  public static string MD5Hash(string input)
        {
            StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] bytes = md5provider.ComputeHash(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(input));

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                hash.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return hash.ToString();
        }
```

The code above whene i tested in ***MD5Hash("MyCode")*** its returned : ***6403df8223bf310152ad235731e79902*** (32 char)

but the md5 on my database is
***0x6403DF8223BF310152AD235731E79902000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*** (64 char)

it's missing the ***"0X"*** in the begginig and the ***"zeros"*** in the ending

Comment: What is the value from database you are passing to this function?

Comment: change Database>Table>Column Type to varchar(32)

Comment: @Amid i can't , the database already fill with users data , i can't change it , and some passwors has 33 chars

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya type of value is binary(64)

Comment: How comes this function returns `6403df8223bf310152ad235731e79902` for `MyCode` ?

Comment: not "MyCode" , i just replace my real code to "MyCode"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your examples, what generates the 64-Chars strings in your database is something like:

```cs
public static string MD5Hash(string input)
{
    using (var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        return string.Concat("0x",
            BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)))
            .Replace("-", string.Empty).PadRight(62, '0'));
}
```

I wouldn't name the function `MS5Hash` in this case and as you can see, the database strings are concatenated strings and the MD5 hash is just the middle part of each.

Answer (score 3):

This is Working for me -

```
    public static string MD5Hash(string text)
    {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        //compute hash from the bytes of text  
        md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));


        //get hash result after compute it  
        byte[] result = md5.Hash;

        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            //change it into 2 hexadecimal digits  
            //for each byte  
            strBuilder.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: it's returning the same value of mine .. thanks for replying

Comment: This is now deprecated use `MD5.Create()` or `MD5.HashData()`

Answer (score 1):

The hash size for the MD5 algorithm is 128 bits.

The ComputeHash methods of the MD5 class return the hash as an array of 16 bytes. Note that some MD5 implementations produce a 32-character, hexadecimal-formatted hash.

So you have to check in the database why are you getting extra characters?

and for your information, the correct MD5 value for `MyCode` will be 8e995273698f53088fe2ad4a0888d213

Code to generate MD5 below.

```
public static string GenerateMD5(string input)
{
    
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5?view=netcore-3.1#remarks

Comment: thanks for replying . i just replace "MyCode" to my real code that's why

Comment: i'm getting extra char bcuz the type of column is binary(64)

Comment: so as suggested please change the length to 32, but still, I doubt why are you getting 0x

Comment: and i can't change the type of the column in database bcuz i can't , i'm working on existing database . thanks

Comment: the admin of database said that they where inserting the password as  ***"HASHBYTES('md5','MyCode')"*** in sql using query

Comment: then you don't need to generate the MD5 in the C# code. just pass the actual value and let the query convert it

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    public static string Md5Hash(string text)
    {
        using (var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            using (var tds = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                tds.Key = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey));
                tds.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                tds.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                using (var transform = tds.CreateEncryptor())
                {
                    byte[] textBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
                    byte[] bytes = transform.TransformFinalBlock(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's this : ***encryptionKey***

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that, its a fixed hashed string   static string encryptionKey { get; set; } = "A!9HHhi%XjjYY4YP2@Nob009X";